# How to Ensure a DropDownList is Required if a given Radio Button is selected?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a RadioButtonLIst as follows:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="Location" ValidationGroup="formVal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Beverly Hills" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="Seattle" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvLocation" 
ControlToValidate="Location">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

If the first radio button is selected, I need to require a selection in the following dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Food" ValidationGroup="formVal">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Chicken" Value="Chicken"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Beef" Value="Beef"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Fish" Value="Fish"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Would I use a CustomValidator to accomplish this?  If so, what validation expression should be used?  If a CustomValidator isn't a good fit, which validator is suggested?

Thanks much:)

UPDATE:  Added the following to code behind

```
protected void LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Location.SelectedIndexChanged == true)
    {
        rfvFood.Enabled = true;
    }
    else rfvFood.Enabled = false;
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. add a RequiredFieldValidator for the DropDownList and set its enabled property to false
2. set AutoPostBack=true on the RadioButtonList
3. in code behind, handle the RaditButtonList's OnSelectedIndexChanged event
4. Here, add logic that enables or disables the RequiredFieldValidator depending on RadioButtonList's selected item

If you don't like the whole page refreshing when the user chooses an option, wrap these controls up inside an UpdatePanel.